# How to make condition "if collection contains resourse with a TV that is equal to [[*id]]"

Tags: modx

I need the following condition in Modx "if collection (resourse #10) contains resourse with a TV that is equal to [[*id]]" then ...

I tried several options but they don't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[!pdoResources?
&parents=`10`
&depth=`1`
&tpl=`nomatter`
&limit=`1`
&includeTVs=`TV_NAME`
&where=`[ "TV":[[*id]] ]`
]]

[[+total:gt=`0`:then=`....`]]
```

https://docs.modx.pro/komponentyi/pdotools/snippetyi/pdoresources

Comment: Спасибо,  все получилось)